# Write shorthand for val++ and if()

Tags: javascript

I do a `val++` at the end of each txt file is loaded and then run `doSome()` when val is equal to `num`.

```
$('#holder').load('item[i].txt',function(){
   val++;
   if(val==num){
      doSome();
   }
}
```

How to I write this shorthand?

```
val++;
if(val==num){
    doSome();
}
```

Comment: IMO what you have there is fine and the more readable than trying to turn it into less lines.

Comment: Is `i` in `item[i].txt` variable?

Answer (score 3):

`val++` already is (basically) shorthand for `val = val + 1;`

You can use `&&` to replace the `if`:

```
val == num && doSome();
```

[<sup>(MDN: && Shortcut operation)</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation)

Resulting in:

```
$('#holder').load('item[i].txt',function(){
   val++;
   val == num && doSome();
}
```

Personally, I prefer having the increment and the condition on separate lines, for readability purposes.

Another suggestion: The brackets for an `if` statement (`{}`) are optional, if the `if` statement is only used for 1 line of code:

```
if(condition) {
    doSomething();
}
```

Can be shortened a bit like:

```
if(condition)
    doSomething();
```

Comment: Exactly, as you said: "I prefer having the increment and the condition on separate lines, for readability purposes."

Comment: `val == num && doSome();`  this will fail JSHint

Comment: JSHint's default rule set contains a couple of rules that are pretty opinionated. I've disabled that specific rule, among some others, in my IDE.

Comment: I have never run my code through a linter before. Standards be damned. I'm after job security.

Comment: I'm curious why this answer was downvoted. If There's something incorrect about it, I'd love to hear what it is, so I can fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Use pre-increment operator

```
if (++val === num) {
    //code here
}
```

This will first increment `val` by one and then compare the updated value with `num` variable.

Comment: Thanks. +10 Can you please explain briefly why there are `===` ?

Comment: @Becky It is strict comparison operator, will compare value of the variables as well as type. Ex. `'10' == 10` is `true` while `'10' === 10` is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

`Pre-increment` could be used where value of `variable` is incremented first and then returned whereas in `Post-increment`, value of `variable` is returned first and then incremented.

```js
if (++val == num) {
  doSome();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

So... maybe this? :) `++val ^ num || doSome();`

`^` (XOR) is a bitwise operator. It returns 0 if two operands are the same number. For example `2^2 = 0`.

So you can firstly pre-increment `val` this way: `++val`. Then you can do XOR operation on num, and when they are equal - it will return 0, which is considered as `false` in logic statements in js. And then, when left side of `||` operator is false, it will execute right part of this statement - `doSome()`.

Btw, one interesting thing: for example, if disable code optimisation, in C++ it is much efficient to assign 0 to variable in this way: `a ^= a` rather than `a = 0`.

Comment: @Cerbrus, it depends.

Comment: @Cerbrus Just shown one of the shortest possible ways of doing this. Noone says you to use this approach.